# I want to return the number of elements in tree which are less than or equal to x

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

//This is the helper function. My function doesn't seem to work, any ideas on why that is? The runtime for this function should also be O(h) h being the height of the tree, which I'm confident it is.

```
private:
static int _num_leq(bst_node *r, const T &x) {
  
  if(r==nullptr) return 0;
  
  if (r->val == x) 
  {
    return 1;
  } 

  if (r->val <= x) 
  {
    return _num_leq(r->left, x) + _num_leq(r->right, x) + 1;
  } 
  else
  {
    return _num_leq(r->left, x);
  }

}
```

Comment: think about these 2 conditions: `if (r->val == x)` and  `if (r->val <= x) `

Comment: `if (r->val == x)   {    return 1;  }` doesn't look right. There might be nodes in the left subtree with values less than `x`, that you are not counting.

Comment: Unless you have a variable storing the number of nodes left/right to that, you can't have a  O(h) algorithm,

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.